# Android: Refreshing listView of neighboring tab inside Viewpager not working

Tags: android, android-viewpager, notifydatasetchanged

I have a viewpager with many tabs in my app. From one of the tabs (say A) I want to change the listView in the neighboring tab (say B). The tab B has an adapter that extends ArrayAdapter. This is what I am doing.

In Tab A

```
ParentFragment parentFragment = (ParentFragment)getParentFragment();
List<Fragment> fragmentList = parentFragment.getChildFragmentManager().getFragments();
for (Fragment fragment : fragmentList) {
    if (fragment instanceof TabB) {
        ((TabB) fragment).adapterB.add(name);
        ((TabB) fragment).adapterB.notifyDataSetChanged();
        break;
     }
}
```

I am not sure if this is the ideal way but I think it should work. However the list in Tab B remains the same when I navigate to B. What is the problem with my approach. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks !!

Comment: Are you sure your fragment are not destroyed when hidden in your viewpager? That's a common behaviour. It depends how much fragment you have, and with what number you used yourViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit)

Comment: @Ben-J , I have set the offscreenPageLimit to the number of tabs in my app.

Comment: The code looks perfect though.

Comment: @jaibatrik I wasn't making changes to the list of adapter TabB, when I added ((TabB) fragment).list.add(name); as well it worked. If I am not wrong we need to do changes just to the adapter.  Isn't it so?

Comment: For it to reflect to the ListView, it is enough to add it to Adapter, given that you are passing the array / list to the super class constructor and not overriding methods like add or notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: @jaibatrik Thanks for the info that helped a lot !!

Comment: BTW, `FragmentManager.getFragments()` is one of those methods that is declared public but is not part of the official API, so it's a good idea to find a different way to get a reference to the TabB fragment.  The method is public for the support library class but not the normal SDK class.